# How to navigate to the other websites or webpages without refreshing the web page using a selector?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I wonder how can I be able to create a webpage like [this](http://www.yootheme.com/demo/joomla/digit)?

so the user can navigate to other websites or pages without seeing their address and just by selecting the desired page from the drop down menu?

here is the other example

http://demo.rockettheme.com/joomla-templates/epsilon/

I have to clarify that the URL that you are visiting in the Address Bar is

http://www.yootheme.com/demo/joomla

But after you have selected the Frequency Theme for example from the menu you are seeing 
this URL again

http://www.yootheme.com/demo/joomla but the frequency theme is hosted here:

http://yoocore.com/demo/themes/joomla/2014/frequency/

and could you please tell me the name of this method or if any specific plugin or tool available to create such a website?

Comment: "without seeing their address" — Don't be evil. Having URLs for pages is the fundamental part of the web that makes it work.

Comment: Thanks,But I meant that you are not seeing the URL of the specific template for example in the Address bar when you choose the Frequency theme from the drop down menu,the Address is not changed but the correct URL for that theme is http://yoocore.com/demo/themes/joomla/2014/frequency/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML/Element/iframe). Here's part of the source code:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" onload="" 
    src="http://yoocore.com/demo/themes/joomla/2014/digit/index.php?style=default"
    border="0" id="iframe" style="top: 56px; left: 0px; width: 1353px; height: 275px;">
</iframe>
```

Comment: So how the website loading the other pages in that Iframe?,is the method of this kind of navigation has a specific name? Thanks A Lot

Comment: @Hbirjand From the link above: "The HTML <iframe> Element (or HTML inline frame element) represents a nested browsing context, effectively embedding another HTML page into the current page" i.e navigation is through ordinary links/forms etc. The address on the address bar only changes if the parent page's location changes.

Comment: It is an IFrame, depending on your use though, using a DIV and AJAX to populate is more common now and days, and more mobile friendly too.